# apache url rewrite connection reset on root directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

in my apache `sites-available/default` file i had change the config to folowing:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All             //originally was AllowOverride None
    FallbackResource rewrite.php  //i added this line, too
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

i wanted to handle all url calls in my own rewrite.php file. this works, when i visit my site at `http://192.168.1.104:4567/web/knxzkcha` but doesnt work when i go for `http://192.168.1.104:4567/web/`. i got this problem in firefox : `The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.`

the index site `http://192.168.1.104:4567/web/index.php` works flawlessly and shows me my index.php file. all i want is to let me show the index file when visiting the root directory, too. `/var/www` points to the `/web` directory. i have some ubuntu 12.04 server 64 LTS edition

when i rewert the config lines, the root gives me the index file by default.

Comment: Can you post your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: i dont have any. at least i have already erased the one i had, after reading i can put the `FallbackResource` into the config directly instead of .htaccess

Comment: Try to comment `FallbackResource` line and restart the Apache.

Comment: @anubhava and what next? this works like the default config i had before

Comment: Are you still getting `server was reset` error after commenting out `FallbackResource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to add `AllowOverride All`, telling apache to avoid IO by checking existence of `.htaccess` files in current directory and all parents directories with `AllowOverride None` is a good recipe for speed. Avoid `.htaccess` files if you can edit Apache configuration.

Now [`FallbackResource`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) is a quite new feature and may have some bugs. Did you check the ErrorLog for details? Could you try that with `LogLevel debug`?

It seems you problems is with directories, maybe you could fix it by enforcing usage of your fallback when a Directory is requested, try to add:

```
DirectoryIndex  rewrite.php
```

Comment: i only added the line `DirectoryIndex  rewrite.php` and it worked. the only problem is that the default root directory goes through the rewrite php script and not default to index.php. but this is not a problem since i simply include index.php inside rewrite.php when no url path is detected.